# YQL: Return single field from yahoo.finance.quotes

Tags: xml, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I've just started working with YQL and I'm stuck with the following problem:
I cannot let YQL return a single value from the yahoo.finance.quotes table.

I would like to just select the "Open" tag in "quotes"

This is the query I am using:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20=%20%22AAPL%22%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222015-01-1%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222015-01-2%22&format=xml&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

[Execute query](http://goo.gl/P2kAyN)

I tried to find a solution in the official documentation, but it does work the way they explain it.
[Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/projection.html)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify to select `"Open"` tag instead of selecting *all* tags (using the asterisk (`*`) means you want all tags). So this query :

```
select Open 
from yahoo.finance.historicaldata 
where symbol = "AAPL" 
      and startDate = "2015-01-1" 
      and endDate = "2015-01-2"
```

..which then translated to the following URL :

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Open%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20=%20%22AAPL%22%20and%20startDate%20=%20%222015-01-1%22%20and%20endDate%20=%20%222015-01-2%22&format=xml&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

..should do exactly what you wanted.